# Dynamically align html content in a div tag

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a div tag and it contains some text in it.At present the text starts from centre which i would like it to become become dynamic based upon the text entered.

```
<div style="max-width: 390px; float: left; height: 30px; margin-top: -12px; vertical-align: middle;padding: 15px 0;">
<p>helo <em>Donald Alfred</em>,how aredhfdfshgdghghjfhjdskf.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: <div style="max-width: 390px; float: left; height: 30px; margin-top: -12px; vertical-align: middle;padding: 15px 0;">
                                    <p>helo Donald Alfred,how aredhfdfshgdghghjfhjdskf</p></div>

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div style="background-color: red; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;
   display: table-cell; padding: 20px; height: 90px;">
   <p>helo <em>Donald Alfred</em> ghghjfhjdskf.</p>
 </div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Tz2L/2/)